# I pulled up the cnosdb cluster through the run_cluster.sh and found that the meta directory did not exist,what' wrong?

Tags: database, shell, time-series, cnosdb

I pulled up the cnosdb cluster through the run_cluster.sh and found that the meta directory did not exist,what' wrong?

```
bash run_cluster.sh
```

I cleck the meta info,as follow:

```
[root@cicd_ujv23 ~]# ll /tmp/cnosdb/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root  38 Aug  7 17:02 1001
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root  38 Aug  7 17:03 2001
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 154 Aug  7 17:12 logs
```

there is no meta directory,

and I check the meta log, as follow(According to the logs, the meta directory does exist):

```
2023-08-07T18:36:59.760905045+08:00  INFO cnosdb_meta: get_sled_db: created log at: "/tmp/cnosdb/meta/journal/1.binlog"
2023-08-07T18:36:59.994172600+08:00  INFO meta::store: state_matchine info: Ok(None)
2023-08-07T18:36:59.994492255+08:00  INFO meta::store: state_matchine info: Ok(None)
```

So, where is the meta directory?